# Laravel error TokenMismatchException&

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I try to register user(using angular js).This is my form:register.blade.php

```
 <div class="panel-footer" id="free-panel-footer">
        <form
          name="registerCtrl.registerForm"
          ng-submit="registerCtrl.submit(registerCtrl.registerForm.$valid)"
          novalidate
          class="register-form"
          autocomplete="off">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

....

In head index file i put this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

but i got error TokenMismatchException in compiled.php line 2927&?

Comment: when you inspect the network tab of your browser do you see any token getting passed?

Comment: No i don't see.

Comment: you might have to use an api route rather than a web route or you can go to VerifyCRSFToken middleware and in the $except[] add the register route ( But this will leave your site vulnerable to csrf attacks)

Comment: Verify the session path is writeable.

Comment: Are you submitting the form or doing ajax call? If you are using ajax, which library are you using to do the ajax calls?

Comment: just saw `ng-submit`, never mind....

Comment: This problem is only on localhost..., on production server is,ok, no difference between projects

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that hidden input you wrote manually with `{!! csrf_field() !!}`. That will print the token for you and you'll be sure it's the correct name and value.

Since you are not submitting the form in a default GET or POST request, you need to add that field manually to the AJAX call you're doing, and you can use that generated field to gather the name and the value of the csrf-token. You will need to do [something like this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) for your javascript.

Just in case nothing of this works, and under your own responsability for the security hole you will create, you can exclude that concrete route from needing the csrf-token on `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken` middleware, adding the path to the `$except` array.

Comment: This problem is only on localhost..., on production server is,ok, no difference between projects